# Python putting multiple arguments inside a mutually exclusive group

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I want to achieve something like this,

```
usage: main.py [-h] [--video_link video | --channel_link channel --num_vids num ]
```

The option --num_vids is only needed if I'm using --channel_link option.

I could only come with this,

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                       description='A Python script to download Youtube videos')
    group_ = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group_.add_argument('--video_link',
                        metavar='video',
                        type=str,
                        help='Enter the video url')
    group_.add_argument('--channel_link',
                        metavar='channel_link',
                        type=str,
                        help='Enter the name of the channel')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    video_link = args.video_link
    channel_link = args.channel_link
    print(video_link, channel_link)
```

How do I implement the desired functionality?

Comment: An `argument_group` inside a `mutually_exclusive_group` won't help.

Comment: Would you be so kind enough to tell me what I should be doing here?

Comment: Is one of `--video-link` or `--channel-link` (option names tend to use `-`, not `_`) required? Consider using subcommands for them instead, and attach `--num-vids` to the sub parser for `channel-link`.

Answer (score 1):

`argparse` support subcommands, which are like positional arguments that can have their own options. You can only specify one subcommand per call (though subcommands can take their own subcommands), but that means subcommands behave much like mutual-exclusion groups. Subcommands are also optional, so you need not specify one at all when running your script. (You can make one required by passing the appropriate argument to the `add_subparsers`, though.) The use of `set_defaults` injects a destination in to the parsed arguments that indicates which, if any, subcommand was used, if you need to distinguish between the two types of URLs, for example.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                   description='A Python script to download Youtube videos')
sp = parser.add_subparsers()
p.set_defaults(choice=None)
p1 = sp.add_parser('video_link',
                    metavar='video',
                    help='Enter the video url')
p1.set_defaults(choice='video')
p1.add_argument('url', help='Video url')

p2 = sp.add_parser('channel_link',
                    metavar='channel_link',
                    help='Enter the name of the channel')
p2.add_argument('url', help='Channel url')
p2.add_argument('--num-vids', type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the num_vids argument to the main parser as an optional argument with a default of 0.  Then you can write your own usage if you want it to look a certain way.

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                       description='A Python script to download Youtube videos', 
                       usage='main.py [-h] [--video_link video | --channel_link channel --num_vids num ]'
    )
    group_ = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    group_.add_argument('--video_link',
                        metavar='video',
                        type=str,
                        help='Enter the video url')
    group_.add_argument('--channel_link',
                        metavar='channel_link',
                        type=str,
                        help='Enter the name of the channel')
    parser.add_argument('--num_vids', 
                        action='store', 
                        help='Only applies when also using --channel_link',
                        type=int,
                        default=0,
                        nargs='?',
                        const=0)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    video_link = args.video_link
    channel_link = args.channel_link
    print(video_link, channel_link)
```